# Finding Distance in KM

Tags: google-maps, laravel

Hello I have a laravel and android app.  Latitudes and Longitudes are posted from the android app to the server.

Now I am supposed to find the distance in km between two points given that the latitudes and longitudes for both location have been provided.

I tried to google it and found this: [mjaschen/phpgeo](https://github.com/mjaschen/phpgeo) which seems to be able to do that.

However a modification has been now made to our system where I have been asked to find the distance between those two locations **by road**, e.g. route length.

I have been told that this is possible with google maps.  However I am not aware of any google map package or api for php/laravel.

Is there a google map package that can help me do this and is this even possible? If yes then how would I go about implementing this?

**Summary: Finding the distance by road between two locations in kilometers assuming coordinates have been supplied for each of those locations.**

Comment: Can you expand upon this "By Road" idea? Is this, "find all roads within X miles of coordinates, THEN calculate distance between each point from each road?"

Comment: Yes please, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: Does it matter where the roads go? Or are "Roads" really "routes" in this case, and you want to find the distance between each coordinate from each route?

Comment: The roads should lead from point A to point B and vise versa

Comment: Ah...so this is not just distance between two points, but to get all routes between 2 points.

Comment: Yes please. Exactly that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122052/discussion-between-ohgodwhy-and-user3718908).